# Firebase cloud function scheduler pricing for multiple users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to write a scheduler to be triggered once every month to do a particular job that affects all users in a firestore database. What I want to know is, if I have for example one million users compared to having just one user in the database. what is the cost of running that scheduler for one user compared to one million users?
The Firebase documentation states that it cost $0.10 per job per month, but this does not seem to take into account the number of users involved.
So does the pricing of the scheduler change depending on the number users, can someone please clarify this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are using three services, each with their own pricing:

1. Cloud Task Scheduled, which charges per job.
2. Cloud Functions, which charges per invocation, and then for the memory/cpu usage for as long as the function is active.
3. Cloud Firestore, which is charged per read/write operation per document, and for the bandwidth used to read data.

The total you pay is the combination of all these services. I recommend putting all your info in the [Google Cloud Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) to get an estimate of the cost, and (more importantly) in the factors that determine that cost.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/pricing#pricing_overview), of Cloud Scheduler - that it seems to be the one you will be using:

> Cloud Scheduler pricing is based exclusively on the job. A Cloud Scheduler job defines a single activity scheduled to run at a frequency provided in the definition.

The number of users is not considered as well directly in the [Cloud Functions pricing](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing), as its per invocations of the function. To summarize, it doesn't matter the number of users, but actually the number of jobs and invocations, that you will need to control, so you can calculate the real cost you will have.